# CSS bugs in FF and IE? Transition including borders yielding unexpected results in both. Or how would I align the behavior?

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a CSS transition which gives the desired result in Chrome, but IE (10 and 11) and Firefox (41) differ (each gives a different result, but they all fail to display the border, see for yourself in the Codepen linked below):

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border: 0px dotted green;
  box-shadow:1px 1px 20px black;
}

.box:hover {
  border: 99px dotted green;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 500px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transform: rotate(2turn)
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EVvrYx

Would you say this a bug in both IE and Firefox? Because the definition of border seems quite straight forward and consistent with the behavior in Chrome.

Yet both FF and IE show nothing at all in the final transition state.

(btw also fun effects if you hover over the edge of the figure in Firefox, not a bug though I guess but only occurs in FF)

Comment: What versions of ie and FF?  See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp - maybe not fully supported with the tested version?

Comment: @JECarterII sorry, updated the question with the version numbers

Comment: Could this be because Chrome uses squares for "dotted" but FF uses circles?

Comment: @Paulie_D, likely the reason for the differences in the state transitions, yet both FF and IE show no border at all in the final transition state, which they are supposed to according to the spec. Note that FF's behavior is even weirder and doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: If you change the border from 99px to 9px and set the border-radius to 100px it seems to work in IE/Edge/FF/Chrome equally though the dotted border differs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have a round div you set the border to 50% of the width/height, more might cause unpredictable result, which might explain the border differences.

If you change the border from 99px to 9px and set the border-radius to 100px it seems to work in IE/Edge/FF/Chrome equally, though the dotted border differs.

And according to this, Firefox has a border/radius bug,  https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=382721, where when you combine border-radius and dotted style, it shows a solid border instead of a dotted.

Comment: Thanks LGSon, so I can't force the dotted border style rendering I guess.. Stil shouldn't it work in either as is and display *some* border in the final transition state? Even with a 50% border-radius there is no dotted rendering in FF at all.

Comment: Well you can, though the outcome can become something you dont want :) ... and I updated my answer a little to mentioned this there as well

Comment: When it comes to FF, it has a bug which says when you combine border-radius and dotted style, it shows as solid. See my link in my answer.

Comment: Btw, if you need dotted border it might work in new browsers if you use `border-image` ... http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_border-image

Comment: Thanks, will look into it!

Answer (score 0):

The Version of the browser might be the issue, I was using IE8 previously and telerik controls were not updated in it. Make sure you update your browser and check if you can see similar behavior.

Comment: I'm using the latest versions (see the updated question with the version numbers) which are supposed to support the transitions.